# key should be unique react native error while mapping data array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a listing component in my react native map. in which I'm mapping the list of items in the component. How the problem is. I have been getting warnings that each child should have a unique key. Even though I have given them a unique key but still getting that warning.

here is the code.

```html
<ScrollView horizontal>
    {this.state.isLoading === true ? (
        [...Array(7)].map((item, index) => <PremiumShimmer key={index} />)
      ) : this.state.isError === true ? (
      <View>
         <Text style={{ color: "black" }}>
           Facing some issue to load data from server
         </Text>
      </View>
      ) : this.state.Data.length === 0 ? (
        <Text style={{ color: "black" }}>No Data Founbd</Text>
      ) : (
        this.state.Data.map((item) => (
         this.ItemRenderer({item})
        ))
      )}
</ScrollView>
```

```js
ItemRenderer ({ item }) {
    return (
        <PremiumItemListComponent item={item} navigation={this.props.navigation} />
    );
};
```

**PremiumItemListComponent**

```
             <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.listBox}
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Detail", { data: this.props.item })}
                >
                <ImageBackground style={styles.listImage} imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 26}} source={{uri:SERVER_URL.apiUrl+this.props.item.background}}>
                    <Text style={{color:"white",fontSize:13,paddingLeft:10,fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{this.props.item.name}</Text>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap',padding:10}}>
                            { 
                                [...Array(5)].map((e, i) =>
                                // 3.688689 will be replaced by rating
                                // console.log(typeof i,typeof 4, i+1<=4)
                                <Ionicons name={i+1<=Number((3.688689).toFixed(0))?"star-sharp":"star-outline"} size={15} color="#FFE600" />
                                )
                            }
                        </View>
                </ImageBackground>     
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

I have console logged `item.ids` and they are unique `23`, `24`, and `25`.
if You need more code to help. You can ask. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Unless you can prove (in your post) this is the exact line that you're getting the error for, I'm pretty sure these are _not_ the map calls that are throwing the error. However, I _am_ going to admonish you for using array position as a key in `<PremiumShimmer key={index} />`. Never do that. The `key` is for uniquely identifying "the thing", and an array index can't. If you sort your array, now you have completely different keys for the same items.

Comment: this is not error. Its warning. and I have added more code.

Comment: Yes, id are unique as i have mentioned unique ids in questions that i'm getting from items.

Comment: When where should i give key if not to `PremiumItemListComponent`

Comment: There is no loop iteration (`Array#map`) over `PremiumItemListComponent`, so there is no need to use `key` attribute there. At least the piece you shared does not have any.

Comment: I have update code and the question as well. The warning is still there that the each child in a list should have a unique key.

Comment: `PremiumItemListComponent` doesn't have a `key`, neither does `Ionicons`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks right, i don't think the warning you are getting for key is from this specific component, but i would like to add a few things to make your life a little easier.

1. Never use Index as key. Index will change if your data changes which will eventually make the purpose of keys useless.
2. Wherever possible use FlatList Component instead of a map since you get a easy *keyExtractor* Prop and it increases your performance if the list is long

Example : -

```
  <FlatList
    data={DATA}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  />
```

using the keyExtractor Prop you can pick out and convert a unique value from your data into a key and it automatically adds the key prop into rendered component wrapper.

Comment: appreciated your answer. and It is helpful. And i am going to replace map with flat list. And i fount the waning part in my code which is inside `PremiumItemListComponent` where i'm mapping `Ionicons`. I did not give unique key to that element. as i gave that it removed warning. by the way you can upvote my question so i can upvote your answer. Right now my rank is low and i can't upvote your answer.